# C# Multi threading reading from network stream

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am currently learning how to implement multi threading so i apologize if this question is really simple to resolve or/and full of simple mistakes!

I have a program, which reads from TCP Client, and I want it to output what it reads from the network stream and display it into a text box. The stream is *continuous* - data is constantly being received.

I have a thread which reads in a line from the network stream and appends it to the text box. I created a thread because I didn't want it to effect the UI.  Here is the code I have tried:

```
 nwStream = client.GetStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(nwStream);
        Thread t = new Thread(ReadInandOutputToTextBoxIfInvoke);
        t.Start(); //this is in the main method


  private void ReadInandOutputToTextBoxIfInvoke()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            ReadInandOutputToTextBox();
        }
        else
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ReadInandOutputToTextBox();
            });

        }
    }
    private void ReadInandOutputToTextBox()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (nwStream.CanRead)
            {
                readInTxtBox.Text = readInTxtBox.Text + reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }
```

However this code has two **issues**:

1. The first issue it reads in all the lines and then displays whereas I want it to read a line and then append it to the text box. For example, at the minute it has a for loop with 10 in it. Instead of reading in a line, displaying it, and repeating this, it reads in all 10 lines and then displays them all at once. I wanted this to be a infinite loop so it would constantly read in the stream however this is obviously not possible.
2. It does effect the UI when running! I cannot use any other part of the WPF when the thread is running which is not what I wanted!

Any help/explanations would be massively appreciated. I am a complete novice at multi threading and it is something I need to brush up on greatly!

Comment: Unless you are using some .NET version below 4, there is no good reason for you to use the Thread class instead of the Task class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto and if you are using below 4 there is still no good reason because there are better mechanics like using the asynchronous methods that are `XxxxxBegin()` and `XxxxxxEnd()` on many types or by using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...)`

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke` runs on the UI thread. So you're doing all of your thread work on the UI thread, so it can't update. And if you are updating the UI every few milliseconds forever (*I wanted this to be a infinite loop so it would constantly read in the stream*) you'll freeze the UI with all of those updates.  And `readInTxtBox.Text + reader.ReadLine();` in an "infinite loop" will result in your application slowing down and eventually crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing dispatcher priority while binding data but also use it only to send result (not doing work in this method):

```
var someNewInput = CalculateNewInput();
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind, (System.Action)delegate
        {
            readInTxtBox.Text += someNewInput;
        });
```

Comment: This works great, only problem is when using a while(true) loop so it continuously does it, it freezes after around 14/15 times.

Comment: Ultimately, you must rewrite it to either have some "refresh rate" (you will be updating for example - each 1 sec) or you have to rewrite it to use async/await as MickyD suggested

Answer (score 3):

> The first issue it reads in all the lines and then displays whereas I want it to read a line and then append it to the text box

1. you should be using `async await` rather than spinning up explicit and expensive threads.  async/await will use I/O completion ports (IOCP) which processes I/O quite efficiently by not having threads block waiting for data to arrive.  Not to mention there is no thread
2. you want to minimize the amount of processing (particularly updating the UI) in I/O callbacks else you will lose data.  For example merely store the received data, perform processing in a different thread by first storing the received data in a circular buffer.  You have complete control on how much data you read at a time thus driving how the screen is updated

> It does effect the UI when running! I cannot use any other part of the WPF when the thread is running which is not what I wanted!

3. Don't use `Invoke` it can cause deadlocks and more importantly blocks the worker thread!
4. Update the UI in the UI thread by processing the data in the circular buffer filled as the result of processing the `await`

Answer (score 0):

> I created a thread because I didn't want it to effect the UI.

You should almost never use the `Thread` type. In your case, since you're doing I/O, `async`/`await` is much more natural:

```
var nwStream = client.GetStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(nwStream);

while (true)
  readInTxtBox.Text = readInTxtBox.Text + await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

Note that `await` doesn't need the `Invoke`/`Dispatcher` mess, since [it automatically syncs back up with the UI thread when the `await` completes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score -2):

First of all, only code that affect the gui must be in

```
if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
```

for the rest no problem, below sample (not compiling)

```
    Task tk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {

   nwStream = client.GetStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(nwStream);

    if (nwStream.CanRead)
         int pos = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, 50);

    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
         readInTxtBox.Text = readInTxtBox.Text + buffer.toString()

    };
```

Comment: [StartNew is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) use `Task.Run` instead or at minimum pass `TaskScheduler.Default` in as one of the arguments.

Comment: Ooh, I'm afraid. You would try to answer the problem rather than quibble again on threads and parallelism. Task.New is no more dangerous than the rest when you know what you do

Comment: Well, besides just using StartNew when you should not, your answer has a fairly large problem with it. Unless you get in to the bad case I linked to `readInTxtBox.Text = readInTxtBox.Text + buffer.toString()` will never run, `CheckAccess()` will always be false.

Comment: _"Ooh, I'm afraid"_ - don't be an imbecile